# Jquery onClick Not Firing

Tags: jquery, css, hyperlink, onclick

I am using a jQuery item slider to create a sliding navigation.

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
    <div class="boxes-wrapper">
        <div id="Apps_Google" class="boxes active">
            <? 
            echo "<div class='box card_grid_static' url='http://mail.google.com'><div style='height: 100px; background: url(http://beta.hcsdoh.org/images/cover.jpg) no-repeat; background-size: cover;'></div><hr><div class='card_padding_footer_grid'><div class='gridtext'>Mail</div></div></div>";
            echo "<div class='box card_grid_static' url='http://drive.google.com'><div style='height: 100px; background: url(http://beta.hcsdoh.org/images/cover.jpg) no-repeat; background-size: cover;'></div><hr><div class='card_padding_footer_grid'><div class='gridtext'>Drive</div></div></div>";
            echo "<div class='box card_grid_static'><div style='height: 100px; background: url(http://beta.hcsdoh.org/images/cover.jpg) no-repeat; background-size: cover;'></div><hr><div class='card_padding_footer_grid'><div class='gridtext'>Calendar</div></div></div>";
            echo "<div class='box card_grid_static'><div style='height: 100px; background: url(http://beta.hcsdoh.org/images/cover.jpg) no-repeat; background-size: cover;'></div><hr><div class='card_padding_footer_grid'><div class='gridtext'>Sites</div></div></div>";
            ?>
        </div>
        <div id="Apps_Classroom" class="boxes">
            <? 

            echo "<div class='box card_grid_static'><div style='height: 100px; background: url(http://beta.hcsdoh.org/images/cover.jpg) no-repeat; background-size: cover;'></div><hr><div class='card_padding_footer_grid'><div class='gridtext'>Classroom</div></div></div>";
            echo "<div class='box card_grid_static'><div style='height: 100px; background: url(http://beta.hcsdoh.org/images/cover.jpg) no-repeat; background-size: cover;'></div><hr><div class='card_padding_footer_grid'><div class='gridtext'>Schoology</div></div></div>";
            echo "<div class='box card_grid_static'><div style='height: 100px; background: url(http://beta.hcsdoh.org/images/cover.jpg) no-repeat; background-size: cover;'></div><hr><div class='card_padding_footer_grid'><div class='gridtext'>ProgressBook</div></div></div>";
            echo "<div class='box card_grid_static'><div style='height: 100px; background: url(http://beta.hcsdoh.org/images/cover.jpg) no-repeat; background-size: cover;'></div><hr><div class='card_padding_footer_grid'><div class='gridtext'>DASL</div></div></div>";
            echo "<div class='box card_grid_static'><div style='height: 100px; background: url(http://beta.hcsdoh.org/images/cover.jpg) no-repeat; background-size: cover;'></div><hr><div class='card_padding_footer_grid'><div class='gridtext'>EdInsight</div></div></div>";
            echo "<div class='box card_grid_static'><div style='height: 100px; background: url(http://beta.hcsdoh.org/images/cover.jpg) no-repeat; background-size: cover;'></div><hr><div class='card_padding_footer_grid'><div class='gridtext'>Behavior Report</div></div></div>";                   
            ?>
        </div>
        <div id="Apps_Instruction" class="boxes">
            <? 
            echo "<div class='box card_grid_static'><div style='height: 100px; background: url(http://beta.hcsdoh.org/images/cover.jpg) no-repeat; background-size: cover;'></div><hr><div class='card_padding_footer_grid'><div class='gridtext'>Instruction</div></div></div>";
            echo "<div class='box card_grid_static'><div style='height: 100px; background: url(http://beta.hcsdoh.org/images/cover.jpg) no-repeat; background-size: cover;'></div><hr><div class='card_padding_footer_grid'><div class='gridtext'>Technology</div></div></div>";
            echo "<div class='box card_grid_static'><div style='height: 100px; background: url(http://beta.hcsdoh.org/images/cover.jpg) no-repeat; background-size: cover;'></div><hr><div class='card_padding_footer_grid'><div class='gridtext'>Learn</div></div></div>";
            echo "<div class='box card_grid_static'><div style='height: 100px; background: url(http://beta.hcsdoh.org/images/cover.jpg) no-repeat; background-size: cover;'></div><hr><div class='card_padding_footer_grid'><div class='gridtext'>PD Express</div></div></div>";
            echo "<div class='box card_grid_static'><div style='height: 100px; background: url(http://beta.hcsdoh.org/images/cover.jpg) no-repeat; background-size: cover;'></div><hr><div class='card_padding_footer_grid'><div class='gridtext'>eTPES</div></div></div>";
            echo "<div class='box card_grid_static'><div style='height: 100px; background: url(http://beta.hcsdoh.org/images/cover.jpg) no-repeat; background-size: cover;'></div><hr><div class='card_padding_footer_grid'><div class='gridtext'>School Works</div></div></div>"; 
            ?>
        </div>
        <div id="Apps_Support" class="boxes">
            <?
            echo "<div class='box card_grid_static'><div style='height: 100px; background: url(http://beta.hcsdoh.org/images/cover.jpg) no-repeat; background-size: cover;'></div><hr><div class='card_padding_footer_grid'><div class='gridtext'>VarTek</div></div></div>";
            echo "<div class='box card_grid_static'><div style='height: 100px; background: url(http://beta.hcsdoh.org/images/cover.jpg) no-repeat; background-size: cover;'></div><hr><div class='card_padding_footer_grid'><div class='gridtext'>Aesop</div></div></div>";
            echo "<div class='box card_grid_static'><div style='height: 100px; background: url(http://beta.hcsdoh.org/images/cover.jpg) no-repeat; background-size: cover;'></div><hr><div class='card_padding_footer_grid'><div class='gridtext'>Naviance</div></div></div>";
            echo "<div class='box card_grid_static'><div style='height: 100px; background: url(http://beta.hcsdoh.org/images/cover.jpg) no-repeat; background-size: cover;'></div><hr><div class='card_padding_footer_grid'><div class='gridtext'>AIMsweb</div></div></div>";
            echo "<div class='box card_grid_static'><div style='height: 100px; background: url(http://beta.hcsdoh.org/images/cover.jpg) no-repeat; background-size: cover;'></div><hr><div class='card_padding_footer_grid'><div class='gridtext'>IEP Anywhere</div></div></div>";
            echo "<div class='box card_grid_static'><div style='height: 100px; background: url(http://beta.hcsdoh.org/images/cover.jpg) no-repeat; background-size: cover;'></div><hr><div class='card_padding_footer_grid'><div class='gridtext'>AR/STAR</div></div></div>";                   
            ?>
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
```

As you can see, the item slider takes the class "boxes" and then makes the items in the nested "box" class slide.

I have no problem making "boxes" a link using:

```
<script>
function notify() {
  alert( "clicked" );
}
$( ".boxes" ).on( "click", notify );
</script>
```

I CANNOT however make a "box" a link using:

```
<script>
function notify() {
  alert( "clicked" );
}
$( ".box" ).on( "click", notify );
</script>
```

The "box" will not fire. Here is a link to the javascript for the slider: http://beta.hcsdoh.org/js/jQuery.Opie.ItemSlider.min.js

I am really at a loss on what is happening. Obviously something is blocking "box" from firing. It is not a dynamically generated tag.

**On further investigation, It looks as if .box fires only in the last ".boxes" wrapper, meaning that .box will fire on the last group of links but not the previous ones. It but be re-written. Is there a way to not re-write it?

Here is a test page: http://beta.hcsdoh.org/index2.php

Comment: I have updated my snippet of code. On further investigation, I have realized .box does fire on the last <div id="Apps_Support" class="boxes"> but it does fire on any of the previous boxes classes. It must be overwritten. Any work around for this?

Comment: Please create a test page for this case so that it may become easy to inspect. Perhaps create a page on your domain with the slider used ?

Comment: Here is a test page....as you can see...it only fires when you click "Support" and then a box div. http://beta.hcsdoh.org/index2.php

Answer (score 0):

you should use document ready

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $( ".box" ).on( "click", function(){
        notify();
     });
});
```

Comment: The OP is asking about the `.box` event - they have stated that they can already fire the `.boxes` event.

Comment: Correct. .boxes will fire but NOT .box. I am trying to get .box to fire.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that slider script is somehow changing the .box divs. Give this a try:

```
$(document).on('click', '.box', notify);
```

Comment: If it doesn't work the slider script may remove the .box classes

Comment: Your jsfiddle works, however it is because the slider script is replacing the .boxes each time that is breaking the fire. So it always works on one group.

Comment: Then you should find a class that is still available when the slider script has done it's job. Try it with the Chrome or FireFox (for example) developer toolbar

Comment: Tried that...the only class available is .boxes and up. Anything inside .boxes is gone except for the last .boxes div. See test page: http://beta.hcsdoh.org/index2.php

Comment: It's not gone, I can see that the last Apps_Support is physically on top of the rest, even if it's content is slid away. Then the rest of the slides are underneath it, that's why you can't click on them. Maybe you can find a solution where the slided are hidden (`display: none;`) when they are not visible on the screen...

Comment: Thank you so much. Brilliant idea. You lead me to the right track...I just added and removed classes as follows and took advantage of z-index.  $( '#google' ).click( function () {   
     $( '#Apps_Google' ).addClass( 'zjump' );
     $( '#Apps_Classroom' ).removeClass( 'zjump' );
     $( '#Apps_Instruction' ).removeClass( 'zjump' ); 
     $( '#Apps_Support' ).removeClass( 'zjump' ); 
 });

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
function notify() {
  alert( "clicked" );
}
    $(window).on( "click", ".boxes", function(){
        notify();
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Ronald01990 for the idea. I solved this issue by adjusting the z-index after each click.

```
$( '#google' ).click( function () {   
    $( '#Apps_Google' ).addClass( 'zjump' );
    $( '#Apps_Classroom' ).removeClass( 'zjump' );
    $( '#Apps_Instruction' ).removeClass( 'zjump' ); 
    $( '#Apps_Support' ).removeClass( 'zjump' ); 
});


$( '#classroom' ).click( function () {   
    $( '#Apps_Classroom' ).addClass( 'zjump' ); 
    $( '#Apps_Google' ).removeClass( 'zjump' );
    $( '#Apps_Instruction' ).removeClass( 'zjump' ); 
    $( '#Apps_Support' ).removeClass( 'zjump' ); 
});


$( '#instruction' ).click( function () {   
    $( '#Apps_Instruction' ).addClass( 'zjump' );  
    $( '#Apps_Google' ).removeClass( 'zjump' );
    $( '#Apps_Classroom' ).removeClass( 'zjump' ); 
    $( '#Apps_Support' ).removeClass( 'zjump' ); 
});

$( '#support' ).click( function () {   
    $( '#Apps_Support' ).addClass( 'zjump' ); 
    $( '#Apps_Classroom' ).removeClass( 'zjump' );
    $( '#Apps_Instruction' ).removeClass( 'zjump' ); 
    $( '#Apps_Google' ).removeClass( 'zjump' ); 
});
```